# How to paginate this Jquery filter

Tags: jquery, filter, pagination

I hope you could help me with [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/1/). Im trying to paginate a list of records that must work when i filter the content or not.

HTML

```
<div class="filter">
    <a href="#category-1">category 1</a>
    <a href="#category-2">category 2</a>
</div>
<ul class="items">
    <li class="category-1">item 1</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 2</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 3</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 4</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 5</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 6</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 7</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 8</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 9</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 10</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 11</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 12</li>
</ul>


<a href="#">Next</a> <a href="#">Previous</a>
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
  $('div.filter').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {   
     $('ul.items li').hide().filter('.' + this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf("#") + 1)).show();
     event.preventDefault(); 
  }); 
});
```

So this are my problems:

1. Pagination will be each 6 records (Show first 6 li's when i click "next" the others).
2. When i click in a category, the pagination just should work for the class that i'm using to filter the records, so if i press "next" or "previous" this just must show the selected category.

Please Feel free to modify my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var total = $("li").length;

$("li").each(function(i,v) {
    var inc = i + '';

    if (i < 10) {
       inc = 1;
    } else {
       inc = parseInt(inc[0]) + 1;
    }

    $(this).addClass('row' + inc);

    if ( i > 9) {
        $(this).addClass('hide');
    }

    if (i % 10 === 0 ) {
        var count = (i / 10) + 1;
        $('.filter').append('<li><a class="paginate ' + count + '" href="#">' + count + '</a></li>');
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/4/

Comment: What about the "next" and "previous" when the content is filtered by category? That's the problem @undefined Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/9/

This normally work with `slice(min, max) function`.
You can set how many items you want to display per page 
`itemsNumber = 6 //you can change this as your requirement`

here is the working code

```
var item = $("li");
var itemsNumber = 6;
var min = 0;
var max = itemsNumber;

function pagination(action) {

    var totalItems = item.length;

    if (max < totalItems) {//Stop action if max reaches more than total items 
        if (action == "next") {

            min = min + itemsNumber;
            max = max + itemsNumber;

        }
    }

    if (min > 0) {//Stop action if min reaches less than 0
        if (action == "prev") {

            min = min - itemsNumber;
            max = max - itemsNumber;

        }
    }

    item.hide();
    item.slice(min, max).show();

}

pagination();


//Next
$("#next").click(function() {

    action = "next";
    pagination(action);

})

//Previous
$("#prev").click(function() {
    action = "prev";
    pagination(action);

})?
```

Comment: Hello @user1193749 Sir That's solve part of the problem and it's great! but the other problem is that when i select a category (Filter the li's by class), category 1 as example, the pagination must work only in the li's with that class (category 1) here your great improvement with the "filter" added http://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/11/. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want it apply only for category1 class then you need to define it instead of just li.

Comment: See my update answer. just change `var item = $("li")` to `var item = $("li.category1")`